# React Using Hooks and Context without re-renders of a component that uses only uses the setter function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using react hooks through my project. I am trying to prevent rerenders of a complex button/interface where I want to open the help modal. However, this button needs to be used throughout the app, without causing rerenders. Is there a way to use the setter without having it force an update of this unrelated component?

Here is the most simplified example of code that I could generate.
This is the provider of the context:

```
// Provider.js
export default function ModalProvider(props: React.PropsWithChildren<{}>) {
  // adding the event state info
  const [helpModalOpen, setHelpModalOpen] = useState(false as any);
  
  const contextValue = {
    helpModalOpen,
    setHelpModalOpen,
  };

  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={{...contextValue}}>
      {props.children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useModalState() {
  const context = useContext(StateContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useModalState must be used within the AppStateProvider');
  }
  return context;
}
```

And this is the very complex component that can not be broken up (Its a video interface):

```
// ComplexButtonToOpenHelpModal.js
export default function ComplexComponent() {
   const {setHelpModalOpen} = useModalState();
   return (
       <ExtremelyComplexComponent onClick={setHelpModalOpen}  />
   );
}
```

While this is a simple example, I need to use similar code throughout this app.

Comment: Hi @DataMike, welcome to StackOverflow! I edited your title a bit to make sure it stays focused on the technical content :) I'm about to leave you an idea or two for your question also, so stay tuned!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible simple solution would be to split your context in to two pieces:

```
// Provider.js
const ModalOpenContext = React.createContext();
const SetModalOpenContext = React.createContext();

export default function ModalProvider(props: React.PropsWithChildren<{}>) {
  // adding the event state info
  const [helpModalOpen, setHelpModalOpen] = useState(false as any);

  return (
    <SetModalOpenContext.Provider value={setHelpModalOpen}>
      <ModalOpenContext.Provider value={helpModalOpen}>
        {props.children}
      </ModalOpenContext.Provider>
    </SetModalOpenContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useModalState() {
  const context = useContext(ModalOpenContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useModalState must be used within the AppStateProvider');
  }
  return context;
}

export function useSetModalState() {
  const context = useContext(SetModalOpenContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useSetModalState must be used within the AppStateProvider');
  }
  return context;
}
```

```
// ComplexButtonToOpenHelpModal.js
export default function ComplexComponent() {
   const setHelpModalOpen = useSetModalState();
   return (
       <ExtremelyComplexComponent onClick={setHelpModalOpen}  />
   );
}
```

You're now passing a stable value to your `SetModalOpenContext.Provider`, so components that subscribe to it using `useSetModalState` will never be forced to rerender, since the value won't change over time.

As you noted in your question, [the React docs point out](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider) that: "All consumers that are descendants of a Provider will re-render whenever the Provider’s value prop changes.".

So, really, the only way to prevent rerenders when you know some piece of the context value will be changing is either to 1) split the context in to separate pieces (like I show above) or 2) use some other mechanism to pass the necessary data around your app.

Comment: This works as long if set state is never changed! Thanks!

Comment: if you ever want some consulting work I have a lot of needs! Also I wasn't kidding about the Venmo!